# Vuejs View app not found Problem Larevel 7

Tags: laravel

this is my first programming with laravel 7 wit vuejs. when i am running programming i got the error was

**View [app] not found. Larevel Vuejs**
i don't know how to solve the problem.
what i tried so far i attached below. i installed all libriaries.

**UserContoller**

```
  public function index()
    {
            return view('welcome');
    }
```

**app.js**

```
  require('./bootstrap');

window.Vue = require('vue');


Vue.component('example-component', require('./components/ExampleComponent.vue').default);


const app = new Vue({
    el: '#app',
});
```

**api.php**

```
Route::get('posts', 'UserController@index');
Route::group(['prefix' => 'post'], function () {
    Route::post('add', 'UserController@add');

});
```

**web.php**

```
   Route::get('{any}', function () {
    return view('app');
})->where('any', '.*');
```

**welcome.blade.php**

```
   <body>
        < <div id="app">
               
            </div>
    </body>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
Route::get('{any}', function () {
    return view('app');
})->where('any', '.*');
```

You try to show a Laravel blade view called `app` here - which doesn't exist. Create a file `app.blade.php` in the folder `resources/views` to load it.

https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/views

**Edit:**
Or, if you want to use `welcome.blade.php` you can change `return view('app');` to `return view('welcome');`